# Using Triggers to handle calculated fields in TeamSystem DB

Tags: teamsystem

In our custom process there are a few fields that are calculated fields. Today I am using Team System events and a web service to calculated these but in all honesty its a little clunky. I had to add a delay because once saved the TFSService does make a change to the Work item a person might want to make another change right away and then get an error stating the Work Item has been changed. So the service waits a bit to make sure all edits are completed (I chose 30 secs.) Other than that its not bad.

I was wondering a trigger in the database would be a good practice or will it cause problems when upgrading to a newer version (i.e. Team System 2010).

Has anyone done this or have any comments on using a trigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to leave the database as is, in case any changes you make interfere with its running.

But having said that, as long as you script your trigger creates and drops, and apply the drop scripts to the database before upgrading, you should be OK.